# Maatwebsite is not fetching data of relational table in laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am try to export csv file with maatwebsite. Query I write is fetching data of other table also with which it is having relation. but it is exporting csv file only with one table data.

```
    $data = SaleOrder::where('id',$id)->with('customers')->get()->toArray();


    return Excel::create('Packlist Sale Order '.$id, function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {

        $sheet->fromArray($data);
        foreach($data as $customer)
        {

          $sheet->fromArray($customer['customers']);

        }

    })->download('xlsx');
```

I want to fetch data of both tables in csv file

Comment: insight foreach multiple time you can't use `$sheet->fromArray($customer['customers']);` like this. so make array data then just paas at once

Comment: how i can do that?

Comment: i am waiting ....

Comment: put `dd($data)` show me data which has  `customers` ?